# New here, just wondering if there's some way I should improve my first question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I posted [What could the hidden message be, involving this binary data set and string of characters?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22972/what-could-the-hidden-message-be-involving-this-binary-data-set-and-string-of-c).

I'm just wondering, since I'm new to Puzzling SE, if there are any guidelines I should be adhering to, or ways I should improve the question to make sure it fits well here.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a great question to me! Welcome to Puzzling.SE! :)

Comment: Well, 110 views later... I'd say you did a pretty good job myself. Congratulations, and welcome to the site!

Comment: I think at this point it might be a good idea to reorganize the question, esp. to reduce the size of the images; and possibly ordering the clues by date and removing clues that are dead ends.